# HashMap values calculation without iterating

Tags: java

I have below map, i want to divide rate with each value in charges map without iterating each entry and constructing new map.Is it possible?

```
final String rate="2";
Map<String,BigDecimal> charges=new HashMap<String,BigDecimal>();
charges.put("tax", new BigDecimal(22));
charges.put("vat", new BigDecimal(200));
charges.put("gross", new BigDecimal(100));
charges.put("principal", new BigDecimal(150));
```

after division

```
charges.put("tax", new BigDecimal(11));
charges.put("vat", new BigDecimal(100));
charges.put("gross", new BigDecimal(50));
charges.put("principal", new BigDecimal(75));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is immutable, so you have to replace the values in the map with new instances. You don't need to construct a new map, however (but you do need to iterate):

```
final BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(rate);

for (Entry<?, BigDecimal> e : charges.entrySet()) {
    e.setValue(e.getValue().divide(divisor));
}
```

Although I suspect that @JonSkeet is correct about using a map at all; a class containing fields corresponding to the keys of your map seems to be more appropriate here.

Comment: it is giving error,if rate is is some thing like "0.1111111111".then i used RoundingMode.HALF_UP, but it is not giving whole value if there is.like 100.00 ,.00 not required here

Comment: @user2684215 Is it producing an error or producing unexpected results? The two are not equivalent.

Comment: after i made a fix with RoundingMode , it is giving wrong result if like "100.00"

Comment: @user2684215 What is the expected result?

Comment: if there is no preceison applied, then 100 should be 100 .if there is precision then it should give the result with precision.i.e 100.02

Comment: try rate has "0.1111112" you will see runtime error "Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result."

Comment: use RoundingMode.HALF_UP, then you can see result like 100.00

Comment: for (Entry<?, BigDecimal> e : charges.entrySet()) {
   e.setValue(e.getValue().divide(divisor,2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
  }

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible?

No. In addition, it's not at all clear that you should be using a map for this in the first place. You'd almost certainly be better off with a `Charge` type with appropriate fields. (That might be 4 fields, or perhaps you could compute some values from other ones.)

You could then add a method to either divide all the relevant field values by a constant amount, or (better IMO) return a *new* instance of the type with the new values (making the `Charge` type itself immutable).

Comment: What is the Charge here?.Can you please more specific.Sorry i dont understand. I dont know the exact fields until run time

Comment: @user2684215: Charge would be your own type to encapsulate the data. Why do you only know the fields at execution time? (That's clearly not the case in your sample code. If your sample code isn't representative of reality, then it's not terribly useful.)

Comment: After calculation of this map,i have to prepare query by iterating each entry. I am not using this map for moving across to the system.So What advantage i will get here,if i convert hashmap to pojo using some third party api or constructing my own.

Comment: @user2684215: You'd get the benefit of having a clearer API in terms of meaning. You haven't really given us much context at all, but the small amount of code in your question is just *begging* for a type to encapsulate the data. Either way, the answer to your actual question is simply "no" - if you really want to keep the data in a map, you'll have to iterate over all the entries. Then get worried if you find there are *some* entries which actually shouldn't be divided...